# How to customize distance between columns in amslatex align environment

Tags: align, amsmath

The following code:

```
\begin{align}
\label{eqn::deflist} \lambda&:= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt \kappa}, &\lambda' &:= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{16/\kappa}} = \frac{\pi \sqrt{\kappa}}{4} = \frac{\kappa}{4} \lambda < \lambda,&\chi &:= \frac{2}{\sqrt \kappa} - \frac{\sqrt \kappa}{2}\\
\label{eqn::fullrevolution} && 2 \pi \chi &= 4(\lambda-\lambda'), &\lambda' &= \lambda - \frac{\pi}{2} \chi\\
\label{eqn::fullrevolutionrho} && 2 \pi \chi &= (4-\kappa)\lambda = (\kappa'-4)\lambda'.&&
\end{align}
```

exceeds my page's width:

[image]

I'm sure there exists a very simple command for customizing the distance between columns, but I was unable to find it. Could you provide me with this information?

Comment: The trick to have control on the intercolumn spacinis to use the `alignat` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can reduce `\minalignsep` but it's a bit cramped. You provided no example so I had to guess your text width based on your image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength\textwidth{-1in}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{align}
\label{eqn::deflist} \lambda&:= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt \kappa}, &\lambda' &:= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{16/\kappa}} = \frac{\pi \sqrt{\kappa}}{4} = \frac{\kappa}{4} \lambda < \lambda,&\chi &:= \frac{2}{\sqrt \kappa} - \frac{\sqrt \kappa}{2}\\
\label{eqn::fullrevolution} && 2 \pi \chi &= 4(\lambda-\lambda'), &\lambda' &= \lambda - \frac{\pi}{2} \chi\\
\label{eqn::fullrevolutionrho} && 2 \pi \chi &= (4-\kappa)\lambda = (\kappa'-4)\lambda'.&&
\end{align}



\renewcommand\minalignsep{2pt}% was 10

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{align}
\label{eqn::deflist} \lambda&:= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt \kappa}, &\lambda' &:= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{16/\kappa}} = \frac{\pi \sqrt{\kappa}}{4} = \frac{\kappa}{4} \lambda < \lambda,&\chi &:= \frac{2}{\sqrt \kappa} - \frac{\sqrt \kappa}{2}\\
\label{eqn::fullrevolution} && 2 \pi \chi &= 4(\lambda-\lambda'), &\lambda' &= \lambda - \frac{\pi}{2} \chi\\
\label{eqn::fullrevolutionrho} && 2 \pi \chi &= (4-\kappa)\lambda = (\kappa'-4)\lambda'.&&
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

The above has the original then the version that fits the text width.

Comment: Dear David, thank you so much but it didn't worked. I asked for the value of `\minalignsep` and it was indeed 10pt, then I redefined it, both inside and outside the environment and nothing changed. I'm using version 2020/09/23 v2.17i of amsmath. There is no error message, only nothing happens. I also tried large values, like 20pt, nothing changed either…

Comment: @yannis changing it inside will not work but changing it outside will (must admit I don't thin I have ever used it before:-) but there is not much flexibility here it may be that there is not enough for your real case) I note you are using left aligned labels and other things so perhaps if you made a test document we could see...

Comment: @yannis  I just changed the code in this answer to `\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}` and the second block still shrinks to fit in the text width.

Comment: Well not in my case, who knows what is interfering. I solved the problem by adding a `\rule{2cm}{0pt` in the last cell, not very elegant. Thank you anyway for your efforts.